# Importing point cloud to Blender?

Tags: point-clouds

I have developed a 3D scanner, this is a relatively fast scan of a big space.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHAK1L_AQig

The scanner works great. it Provides text files in X; Y; Z format

The only program I have succeeded to import this is Meshlab. Now trying to import to Blender via Meshlab in .ply format. Something gets imported but it appears as a sphere, I just can not find a way to get this right, any help would be appreciated.

Here are the files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7y_Hbr29sx8WFppMjhZUm5ZR1k
.TXT directly from scanner and .PLY converted with Meshlab. both open ok on Meshlab, but not on Blender, see the Image.

Comment: Not totally related to your question, but can you share how you built your 3D scanner?  That's something I've been wanting to do; seems like there are a lot of different ways of doing it and I'm trying to figure out what direction I want to go in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

ply file imported.  Scaled as indicated in image below.

Comment: I see now it was just misreadings around the sensor I was viewing originally. Must remove those.

Comment: Would there  be a easy way to import X; Y; Z ASCII format directly without going trough Meshlab, Or maybe I should look into making the scanner to generate a PLY directly...